# How to run pose estimation inference with an IP cam (ESP32-CAM) instead of webcam with Teachable Machine in HTML?

Tags: html, esp32, ip-camera, arduino-esp32, teachable-machine

I am trying to replace the default webcam funtion in the teachable machine default pose detection code to detect from the camera feed of an IP camera. I cant find any documentation or similar projects to what i'm trying to achieve

```
        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
    const size = 500;
    const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
    webcam = new tmPose.Webcam(size, size, flip); // width, height, flip
    await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
    await webcam.play();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

The camera is an ESP32-CAM and is currently running off of the CameraWebServer example code from the Arduino IDE. I have tried to replace the default camera on my system to the IP cam so the webcam function stays the same but nothing as worked so far. This leaves the option of somehow replacing the webcam function in the code with the camera feed from the IP Camera.